# What is the best source to learn Random-forest algorithm in Matlab from scratch?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, matlab

I want to understand details of Random-forest algorithm. For this I want to be able to code the Random-forest trees from scratch, does anybody know a good source for the beginners ?

Answer (score 2):

Matlab already provides a function for 'Random forest'. It is the 'TreeBagger' function. More info in https://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.html

To understand basics of Random forest algorithm, these resources are good.
https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the 'questions and answers' section of MATLAB itself. For instance at https://au.mathworks.com/search/site_search.html?c[]=entire_site&q=random-forest+trees